# How can refresh ListView when tab in android

Tags: android

My application have three tabs with `ListView` display inside each one. How to write code to refresh `ListView` when click between tabs ?

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {        
    if(tabId == "tab_1")
    {
        refresh ListView ???
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't refresh the `ListView`. You ensure the underlying `Adapter` has the latest data, and it will work with the `ListView` to display it. So, for example, if you are using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, call `requery()` on the `Cursor`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to refresh manually, you can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should do two things:
- you have to ask adapter to notify ListView of new data changes: notifyDataSetChanged()
but that will make effect next time ListView requires a view to show (let say after scrolling list). Another problem is that ListView will not ask for number of rows in list, so if list became shorter, you will get null pointer exception :)

What i prefer to use is something like:

```
if(filterProvider.containsChildren(position)){
// go into the hierarchy
    filterProvider.navigateToChildren(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    listView.invalidateViews();
}else{
    int ID = (int)filterProvider.getIdFromPosition(position);
    activity.setResult(ID);
    activity.finish();
}
```

Code is a part of a list with multiple levels (with hierarchy)

Greetings,
Sasha Rudan